# How to use the memory of the Xilinx-FPGA Virtex5/7 as a memory mapped into the x86-CPU's address space?

Tags: fpga, xilinx, dma, memory-mapping, virtex

Is it possible to use the memory of the Xilinx-FPGA Virtex5/7 as a memory mapped into the virtual and/or physical address space of the Intel x86_64-CPU's memory and how to do it?

As maximum, I need to use unified single address space with having of direct memory access (DMA) to the memory of FPGA from CPU (like as simple memory access to CPU-RAM).

- CPU: x86_64 Intel Core i7
- OS: Linux kernel 2.6
- Interface connection: PCI-Express 2.0 8x

Comment: What CPU? What system?  How are they connected?

Comment: @Carl Norum  Ok. I added clarification.

Answer (score 1):

You can in theory.

You'll need to write a bunch of VHDL/Verilog to take the PCIe packets and respond to them appropriately, by controlling the address, data and control lines of the internal memory "BlockRAMs", to do its reading and writing.  Treating all the BlockRAM as one massive memory is likely to have routing congestion problems I imagine though!